# Reading and writing digital using a NI DAQ Device PCIe6321 with Python

Tags: python

Reading and writing digital using a NI DAQ Device PCIe6321 with Python has low performance. I got up to 1 kHz. Here is the code. Python steadily works out an input signal of 300 Hz and the output is also synchronously 300 Hz. When the frequency is raised to 5 kHz, chaotic signals are obtained at the output, which are not synchronous with the input. And you need to raise the input frequency to 50 kHz.
Is it possible to increase the exchange rate to 50 kHz. Or is it not possible in Python? Thanks for your attention and advice.

```
import math
import numpy as np
import time
import nidaqmx
import nidaqmx.system
system = nidaqmx.system.System.local()
system.driver_version
for device in system.devices:
    print(device)
with nidaqmx.Task() as input_task, nidaqmx.Task() as output_task:
    input_task.di_channels.add_di_chan("Dev1/port0/line2")
    output_task.do_channels.add_do_chan("Dev1/port1/line3")
    input_task.start()
    output_task.start()
    while True:
       input_data = input_task.read(number_of_samples_per_channel=1)
       output_task.write(np.array(input_data, dtype=bool).tolist())
```

Comment: 50 kHz would mean 20µs per Loop, or 10µs per read and write statement.
This seems "too fast" for python nidaqmx statements, hence the observed hickups. Have you looked at sample rates for your task? See e.g. https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA00Z0000019ZWxSAM&l=de-DE  - would this solve your measurement option?

Comment: My task is to read a signal with a frequency of 50 kHz, then synchronously with these pulses output the data from the matrix to the digital output. If Python cannot provide such a speed, then you can advise what will cope with such a task.

Comment: I am not aware of any solution which would provide this speed with this hardware. Maybe daqmx has some functionality to have a "hardware-timed" approach, but I could not find any. Maybe the NI-Forum https://forums.ni.com/t5/Digital-I-O/bd-p/70 could be of help?